# Combine information from two XML files with one XSL

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have two XML files with different information in it:

**example.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="stylesheet.xsl"?>
<root>
  <Module Name="Module A">
    <Message>1</Message>
    <Message>3</Message>
  </Module>
  <Module Name="Module B">
    <Message>1</Message>
    <Message>2</Message>
    <Message>4</Message>
  </Module>
</root>
```

and

**messages.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<messages>
  <message number="1">
    <description en="Message One" de="Meldung Eins" />
  </message>
  <message number="2">
    <description en="Error" de="Fehler" />
  </message>
  <message number="3">
    <description en="Warning" de="Warnung" />
  </message>
  <message number="4">
    <description en="Message XY" de="Meldung XY" />
  </message>
</messages>
```

now I have created a XSL file to combine the information

**stylesheet.xsl**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <body>
                <h2>Messages</h2>
                <table border="1">
                    <tr bgcolor="#d3d3d3">
                        <th>Module Name</th>
                        <th>Message</th>
                        <th>Description EN</th>
                        <th>Description DE</th>
                    </tr>
                    <xsl:for-each select="//Message">
                        <tr>
                            <xsl:variable name="num">
                                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                            </xsl:variable>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="../@Name"/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                            </td>
                            <xsl:for-each select="document('messages.xml')//message">
                                <xsl:choose>
                                    <xsl:when test="$num = @number">
                                        <td>
                                            <xsl:value-of select="description/@en"/>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <xsl:value-of select="description/@de"/>
                                        </td>
                                    </xsl:when>
                                </xsl:choose>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </tr>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and to get an output like this

| Module Name | Message | Description EN | Description DE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Module A | 1 | Message One | Meldung Eins |
| Module A | 3 | Warning | Warnung |
| Module B | 1 | Message One | Meldung Eins |
| Module B | 2 | Error | Fehler |
| Module B | 4 | Message XY | Meldung XY |

Is there an easier way to solve this problem than using two for-each inside each other?

I am working with XSLT 1.0

Comment: Can’t you just use a xpath query to select the message that has the relevant value directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only use these two values, you don't need the for-each. Define a variable for the document, one in the for-each and access the error message texts by XPath (as already mentioned in the comments):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:variable name="docMsg" select="document('messages.xml')//message" />

...

<xsl:for-each select="//Message">
    <tr>
        <xsl:variable name="num" select="." />
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="../@Name"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="$docMsg[@number=$num]/description/@en"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="$docMsg[@number=$num]/description/@de"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</xsl:for-each>
```

But if you wanted to iterate over all of the attributes, you could make use of the for-each:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//Message">
    <tr>
        <xsl:variable name="num" select="." />
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="../@Name"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </td>
    <xsl:for-each select="$docMsg[@number=$num]/description/@*">
        <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </td>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </tr>
</xsl:for-each>
```

This iterates over all attributes of `<description>` (one column for each). But pay attention that the attributes must always be in the same order in the element. If they're not, you could sort them with an `<xsl:sort select="local-name()" />` in the inner for-each.